# How to cancel pending transaction of ethereum from exchange wallet?

Tags: etherscan, hash, wallet-transfer

How to cancel pending transaction of ethereum from exchange wallet? It is pending for around 36 hours now. There is no available tx hash.

Comment: Is there a way to cancel it if I dont have the Tx hash?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no solution for this.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question - the marked duplicate is about general transactions and this question is about a transaction from an exchange. This transaction may not have even reached the blockchain yet.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen It should have been closed as a question for closed source third party service.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to cancel the transaction (even if you know the tx hash)

It is most likely pending for a long time, because of the low gas price.

It might take you a few days until your transaction gets through.

If you know your transaction's gas price is under 3 it takes a long time.

For current gas prices see here: https://www.ethgasstation.info/

Comment: I would claim there is a high possibility that the transaction hasn't even been broadcast to the blockchain (yet). Exchanges do a lot of work outside blockchain and try to avoid costly blockchain transactions whenever possible.

Comment: Do you have idea if how long will it take to be processed?

Comment: I don't know about the gas price it used to send. It could possible take a few days to weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cancel a transaction if it's broadcast into the blockchain already. But exchanges may work in mysterious ways and it might not be even broadcast (yet). Having the tx hash wouldn't help you cancel it but would make sure that it's broadcast and therefore uncancellable.

The only thing you can do is contact the exchange.

Comment: The transaction is still pending and no update from the support from the exchange. Is there anything I can do for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't think there is. As I said, it may not be even broadcast to the blockchain (yet) - it may just be stuck in the exchange's internal processes for some reason. In any case the exchange is the only one who can possibly do something about it.

Comment: Thanks. The support team from the exchange is useless. No one is answering my emails.